How to email directly to a user using the share plus flutter package?
I want to be able to include any attachments as well as write the subject, description, to and from email address from the flutter app itself.
I am using share_plus to write email from the app and redirect user to the email app to send the email. Using file_picker to select the files from device and attach to email.
The problem is that I am unable to specify the receiver's address in the email. I don't want the user to type the receiver's address, it should be pre-written.
 if (filePath != null) {
      await Share.shareXFiles(
        <XFile>[XFile(filePath)],
        subject: subjectController.text,
        text: descriptionController.text,
      );
    }

I am able to achieve the recipient/receiver's email address using url_launcher, but I can't attach any files in the email directly from the flutter app.
 final Uri emailUri = Uri(
      scheme: 'mailto',
      path: 'srasti.verma@coditas.com',
      queryParameters: <String, String>{
        'subject': subjectController.text,
        'body': descriptionController.text,
      },
    );

But unable to attach any files.

Try to use flutter_email_sender package for send attachment with predefined receiver address.
